# HTML Body Won't Slide To The Right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote up some JQuery/Javascript, wanting to create a slide in menu that pushes the background image aside. The menu itself slides in fine, but for some reason I can't get the body to move over. Here's the JavaScript, HTML, and CSS.

```js
var main = function(){
$('.icon').click(function()
{
$('.menu').animate({
left: "0px"
}, 200);

$('.body').animate({
left:"300px"
}, 200);
});
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
body {
 background-image: url(http://wallpapercave.com/wp/U7rb02o.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 left: 0px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
}
.menu {

 background-image: url((https
://image.freepik.com/free-vector/white-cubes-pattern_1053-248.jpg))
 background: url("https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/white-cubes-pattern_1053-248.jpg");
 background-repeat: repeat;
 background-position: left top;
 background-image: url(http://wallpapers.ae/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Black-Pattern-Background-Wallpaper.jpg);
 height: 100%;
 width: 300px;
 position: fixed;
 left: -300px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.icon {
 padding-top: 25px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-bottom: 25px;
 width: 75px;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JQuery Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="body">
<div class="icon">

</div>
</div>
<div class="menu">
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did make a mistake in not placing the period, however, changing it to '.body' isn't making the body slide over. So not quite :P

Comment: It works if you also change `body` to `.body` in the CSS.

Comment: Not quite. See, '.body' would be selecting a div element with the class "body". If I were to change body to .body in the CSS, the background image would only cover the .body div, so most of the page would be blank. I want the body element to move over, not the ".body" class.

Comment: That is kind of unusual (moving the `body` element). In this case, the element actually moves, the image doesn't and that is probably because it is set as the background.

Comment: I've been learning this on a website called Coddecademy. I was essentially trying to imitate a code that they teach, just to re-enforce what I learned. The code they teach there works just fine, and moves the body to the side. I'm attempting the same thing. Any ideas on how I can fix this code I already wrote so I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.icon').click(function(){
    main();
  });
});

function main() {
  $('.menu').animate({
    left: 0
  }, 200);

  $('.body').animate({
    left: "300px"
  }, 200);
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
body {
 background-image: url(http://wallpapercave.com/wp/U7rb02o.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 left: 0px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
}
.menu {

 background-image: url((https
://image.freepik.com/free-vector/white-cubes-pattern_1053-248.jpg))
 background: url("https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/white-cubes-pattern_1053-248.jpg");
 background-repeat: repeat;
 background-position: left top;
 background-image: url(http://wallpapers.ae/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Black-Pattern-Background-Wallpaper.jpg);
 height: 100%;
 width: 300px;
 position: fixed;
 left: -300px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.icon {
 padding-top: 25px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-bottom: 25px;
 width: 75px;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 40px;
  z-index:999;
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="body">
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
<div class="menu"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write out the code, but I actually just realized a quick change I could make to achieve the same. Instead of applying the background image to the body, I just made a div after the menu div that didn't have an end. So a <div> without a </div>. I applied the background image to this, and made it so the div is 100%height. After that it worked like a charm :)

Comment: Forgive me for saying, but that isn't a valid solution - here's why. There is no such thing as a `<div>` without a `</div>`. If you code it that way, the browser will automatically supply the closing tag *(browsers do that automatically these days - basic error checking)* So that is not what fixed your problem, even though it might look like it. What I did above to fix your problem (and I apologize that I didn't have the extra few seconds at that time to explain) was to move the jQuery click event ***out of*** the `main()` function. That is what solved it.